# VBA - xlsx file creates temporary file when being opened

Tags: vba, excel

I <strike>stole</strike> borrowed some VBA code from Stackoverflow to loop through XLS/XLSX files in a designated directory. Once I get this to work I'm going to export each worksheet in the files in this directory to csv files.

The problem is that when it finds an xlsx file, it creates a temporary ~$blah.xlsx file. Since the if statement opens all files in the directory, it errors out since this is not a regular Excel file. Is there a way to get it to skip the temp files?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
Sub select_rows()

strPath = "C:\exceldocs"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If (objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xls" Or objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xlsx") Then
' Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path)
' Include your code to work with the Excel object here
MsgBox (objFile.Name)
' objWorkbook.Close True 'Commented out because this crashed the routine
End If

Next

objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: The temporary file should be removed when you close the file so it should never get processed anyway, but you could simply test if the file name starts with "~" and then skip it.

Comment: That's what I thought. I figured the "objWorkbook.Close True" line would close the file and the temporary file would be removed, but it didn't work. I guess I'll skip files beginning with tilde.